# Proof that that maximal and minimal $C^{*}$ tensor norms are actually 'largest' and 'smallest' norms?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I'm looking for the proof of the following theorem, and can't seem to find one online that's accessible (as in, it's behind a paywall or perhaps buried in some paper).

Theorem: Let $A,B$ be $C^{*}$ algebras.  Then the maximal and minimal norms $||\cdot||_{\max}$ and $||\cdot||_{\min}$ respectively on the algebraic tensor $A \odot B$ are the largest and smallest $C^{*}$ norms on $A \odot B$.

This seems maybe somewhat obvious from their names, but I was wondering if the proof was available somewhere to look at.  From looking online, it seems that it's located in "M. Takesaki: Theory of Operator Algebras I, Springer, 2001" but that's locked behind a paywall.

If anyone could provide a link, that'd be extremely helpful!

Comment: Presumably you mean the largest and smallest $C^{\ast}$ norms which restrict to the given norms on $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Proving that the maximal norm is actually the largest norm follows (more or less) from the definition.  The corresponding statement about the minimal norm requires a bit of work, and the proof is by no means "behind a paywall".  You can find many excellent lecture notes on the theory of $C^*$-algebras which contain an introduction to their tensor product theory, freely available, from an appropriate internet search.

Comment: As Aweygan says, for the maximal norm, the result is more or less direct. For the minimal norm, you can find one approach on Murphy's book, and another one in Brown-Ozawa.